# Trying to start a file from the same folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

so I have a project, in the main folder of the project, I have imported my other project.
I want to add a code to a button which will debug my other project, I tried to attach this code to a button: `Process.Start(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\REQ Clicker\bin\Debug\REQ Clicker.exe")`. It sais: We cannot find this file. Do you have any ideas what the problem could be, thankyou, I need some help here.

Comment: The `DirectoryPath` is probably some `bin/Debug` folder itself. Be aware that this will not start or attach the debugger.

Comment: Nico Schertler THANKYOU SOO MUCH! You really made my day!!! Thanks!!! :) :D